# Question about GPU Panic on Mid 2010 MacBookPro6,2

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

I've read endless threads about this issue, but there is something I haven't found yet and I hope somebody could suggest something.
For what I've read so far, a considerable amount of MBPs manufactured during 2010 has a latent problem in the hardware that crashes the system.
This problem has emerged usually after upgrading the OS to Lion or latter versions.

**Question 1:** 
it's not yet clear to me what it is bugged. Is it the GPU (Nvidia GeForce 300M) or the logic board? I've heard that many people had the logic board changed. I suppose a 'logic board' is the 'mother board', right?

**Question 2:**
I'm the owner of a MBP manufactured in 2010, but I haven't upgraded the OS so far, so I'm happy with my Mac. But now I need to upgrade, and I'm afraid I could have a bad surprise.
**Is there a way to detect if my laptop is affected by this hardware bug before upgrading the OS?** Maybe a testing tool to examine the hardware under stressing GPU switching? If anybody can suggest **a proven test to run on Snow Leopard**, I'll be grateful.

**Question 3**: being that a hardware related issue, it's not possible to be fixed by software patches. Why has it been latent on many Snow Leopard OS powered machines, then?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure about occurrence depending on OS. I can only answer Q1. Motherboard equals Logicboars equals mainboard. In the case of a MacBook (or most notebooks for that matter) the mainboard includes CPU and GPU meaning a mainboard swap means new Intel and NVidia chip

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer to 5 similar questions. I tried everything from the Kext changes to the [Github](https://github.com/julian-poidevin/MBPMid2010_GPUFix) patch. I also tried to use Gfx. However, here's what worked for me. The latest version of Gfx doesn't set the MBP to use the Integrated card permanently. However, GFx version [v1.8.1](https://github.com/codykrieger/gfx.io/raw/gh-pages/downloads/gfxCardStatus-1.8.1.zip) does. Open it and set it to use Intel.

[image: gfx v1.8.1]

[image: My preferences]

I have not had a GPU panic for 2 days. I also disabled SIP and installed the Github patch, but I still had Panics after that (however, this might be a solution thats GFx only, or maybe the patch also helped. Try Gfx 1.8.1 first)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io/), which is a free/open-source utility that could solve the problem instead of a $2,300 graphics card. In addition to a [zipped download](http://gfx.io/downloads/gfxCardStatus-2.3.zip), it can also be installed as a [Homebrew Cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask#readme) ([source](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/gfxcardstatus.rb)):

```
brew cask install gfxcardstatus
```

My system was severely affected with these panics, but that stopped happening after using that utility.

Answer (score 0):

i never had the problem with Snow Leopard, Lion or Mountain Lion. When I upgraded to Mavericks it started to crash the os..Kernel Panic after an hours use. I figured Mavericks was buggy and upgraded to Yosemite which caused the crash very rapidly and would crash even if there was no software installed (just the os installed)

There is a test you can do
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

My understanding is every unit will have this problem after getting taxed by the higher demands of the new operating systems. The fact that Apple charges for a repair which was caused by their operating system blows my mind.